# How to upload a file to a document library in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a byte[] data and I want to upload it to sharepoint site using c#. I also want to pass credentials for it. Can anyone please guide me.

The code I tried is:

```
        Uri destUri = new Uri("http://test.net/excel/docs/Forms/AllItems.aspx/");
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(destUri);
        req.Method = "PUT";
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        using (req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            string destFilename = @"\\test.net\excel\docs\501.xls";
            byte[] data = new byte[10];
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destFilename, data);
        }
```

ERROR:

```
Access Denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Current user should have add permissions on this library

```
public void UploadFileToDocmentLibrary(Byte[] contentArray)
{
    using (SPSite sharePointtopLevelSite = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
    {
        SPWeb websiteCollection = sharePointtopLevelSite.AllWebs["webName"];
        websiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        websiteCollection.Lists.IncludeRootFolder = true;
        SPList docLibrary = websiteCollection.Lists["listName"];
        SPFile file = websiteCollection.Files.Add(websiteCollection.Url.ToString() + "/" + docLibrary.Title.ToString() + "/" + "fileName.ext", contentArray);
        file.Update();
     }
}
```

If user without permissions should do it, use RunWithElevatedPrivileges statement

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirements properly, you need to upload file into *SharePoint On-Premise*, right?   There are several options on how to accomplish it.

### Send file via HTTP POST using .NET

At least the following components could be utilized for that purpose:

- [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

**Example**

The example demonstrates how to upload file using [WebClient.UploadFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
public static void UploadFile(Uri targeUri, ICredentials credentials, string fileName)
{
     using (var client = new WebClient())
     {
         client.Credentials = credentials;
         //client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
         var targetFileUri = targeUri + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName);
         client.UploadFile(targetFileUri, "PUT", fileName);      
     }
 }
```

**Usage**

```
 var filePath = @"C:\Documents\SharePoint User Guide.docx";
 var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
 UploadFile(new Uri("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/documents"),credentials, filePath);
```

### Using Microsoft SharePoint Server Object Model

```
using (var site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
       var targetFolder =  list.RootFolder;
       var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
       var fileUrl = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
       targetFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, fileContent);
    }
}
```

### Using Microsoft SharePoint Client Object Model

- [SharePoint 2010 Client Components SDK](http://SharePoint%20Foundation%202010%20Client%20Object%20Model%20Redistributable)
- [SharePoint 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

How to upload a file to a SharePoint site using [File.SaveBinaryDirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect%28v=office.14%29)

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
     ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
     using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
     {
         var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
         var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
         ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
         ctx.ExecuteQuery();
         var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

         Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl, fs, true);
     }
}
```

## Using SharePoint Web Services

How to upload file using [Copy Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
 var webUri = new Uri("http://contoso.sharepoint.com");
 string sourceUrl = @"C:\Documents\SharePoint User Guide.docx";
 string destinationUrl = webUri + "/documents/SharePoint User Guide 2013.docx";
 var fieldInfo = new FieldInformation();
 FieldInformation[] fieldInfos = { fieldInfo };
 CopyResult[] result;
 using (var proxyCopy = new Copy())
 {
      proxyCopy.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx";
      proxyCopy.Credentials= new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

      var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sourceUrl);

      proxyCopy.CopyIntoItems(sourceUrl, new[] { destinationUrl }, fieldInfos, fileContent, out result);
  }
```